# GA virtual page event - double ecomrece product list clicks

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have logging products click using Google tag manager datalayer as:

[image]

Also, I have virtual page view event as:

[image]

I found that the virtual page cause double clicks in the e-commerce products performance list if virtual page tag is called after product click tag.

[image]

```
   analytics.logProductClick('flight', selectedFlight, 1, searchParams.travellers)
   analytics.logVirtualPageView('/personalData/', 'Personal data')
```

when I comment the virtual page log than double click issue gone

```
analytics.logProductClick('flight', selectedFlight, 1, searchParams.travellers)
//analytics.logVirtualPageView('/personalData/', 'Personal data')
```

After investigation I found, that virtual page tag creates and call this on my code (This is reason why ecomerce clicks haven`t been counting correctly):

```
ga("create", "UA-xxxxx-xx", {name: "gtm2834", cookieDomain: "auto"})
ga("gtm2834.set", "&gtm", "xxxxxxxx")
ga("gtm2834.set", "dimension2", "1534944292553.6qexcrcl")
ga("gtm2834.set", "dimension3", "2018-08-22T16:24:52.553+03:00")
ga("gtm2834.set", {anonymizeIp: true, forceSSL: true, customTask: function(){ console.log('[function]')}, title: "Personal data", page: "http://localhost:3000/results/VNO-OSL/2018-09-05/2018-09-10/6,3,0/6d46223577ba861c8b57a07880194ae4829aacb4-665d46424f9fe93b11c35a55708fc8010943bb9f/?currentStep=flightDetails"})
ga("gtm2834.set", "hitCallback", function(){ console.log('[function]')})
ga("gtm2834.require", "ec", "ec.js")
ga("gtm2834.ec:addProduct", {name: "VNO|OSL|OSL|VNO", id: "Flights", price: 2154.75, brand: "Lufthansa|Austrian Airlines", category: "Europe/Noorwegen/Oslo", variant: "05-09-2018|10-09-2018|1xoverstap|1xoverstap", coupon: "VNO|OSL|9|6|3|0|Economy", position: 0})
ga("gtm2834.ec:setAction", "click", {list: "FlightSearch|VNO|OSL|9|6|3|0|AF=No|Economy|Recommended", action: "click"})
ga("gtm2834.send", "pageview")
```

Comment: when are you sending the virtual page view event?

Comment: at once after product click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that virtual event trigger tags with enhanced e-commerce on, it was the double issue source.

[image]